# Push into a List and Pop Conditionally in Mongoose and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a list of scores for a user in mongoDB by adding a new score 1 at a time and sorting the list. I want to remove the lowest score when the list grows larger than 5 elements.

The reason for this is because I want to store the top 5 scores of the user.

What would be the best way to do this? Is there a way to make the whole thing an atomic operation?

My code is below. I'm using NodeJS with Mongoose and MongoDB.

```
const maxScoresToStore = 5

var scoreEntrySchema = new Schema({
    score: Number,
    when: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})

var scoreSchema = new Schema({
    _userid: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' },
    username: {type: String, index:{unique: true}},
    scores: [scoreEntrySchema]
})

const scoreModel = mongoose.model("Scores", scoreSchema)

exports.addUserScore = (uid, uname, score) => {
    var query = {_userid:uid, username:uname},
        update = { $push : {"scores" : {$each: [{"score": score}], $sort: {"score":-1}}} }, // sorts in descending order after pushing
        options = { upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true };

    scoreModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).then(
        (result)=>{
            if(result.scores.length > maxScoresToStore)
            {
                // ToDo:
                // result.update({$pop: {"scores" : 1 }}) // pops the last element of the list
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you use local mongodb or something like MongoDB atlas?

Comment: @SuleymanSah A local mongodb server.

Comment: Hmm, we could use MongoDB transactions to achieve atomicity if the server was not standalone. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html

Comment: Is there anyway I can do it using the update query in addUserScore()?

Comment: Yes there seems a few ways to do this, please check the following answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add slice option to your update option:

```js
 update = {
    $push: {
      scores: { $each: [{ score: score }], $sort: { score: -1 }, $slice: maxScoresToStore }
    }
  }
```

Here is the full method code written in async/await style:

```
exports.addUserScore = async (uid, uname, score) => {
  const query = { _userid: uid, username: uname };
  const update = {
    $push: {
      scores: {
        $each: [{ score: score }],
        $sort: { score: -1 },
        $slice: maxScoresToStore
      }
    }
  };
  const options = {
    upsert: true,
    new: true,
    setDefaultsOnInsert: true,
    multi: true
  };

  try {
    let score = await scoreModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);
    if (!score) res.send(404).send("Score not found");
    res.send("Everything is ok");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use $slice operator, And your query looks like:

```
let score = await scoreModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _userid: uid, username: uname },
 {
    $push: {
      scores: {
        $each: [{ score: score }],
        $sort: { score: -1 },
        $slice: maxScoresToStore
      }
    }
  },
 {
    upsert: true,
    new: true,
    setDefaultsOnInsert: true,
    multi: true
  });
```

[DO VOTE TO THIS ANSWER, IF ITS HELPFUL TO YOU]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain If this would help, but it might work

```
scoreModel.update(
    { "scores.5": { "$exists": 1 } },
    { "$pop": { "scores": 1 } },
    { "multi": true }
)
```

As you are already sorting by descending, you can check if the array length is greater than 5 by using `scores.5`, If this returns true then you can `pop` the last element using `$pop`.

If `$exists` return false then it will skip the query. you can run this `update` after `.then()` and you won't have to use `if` condition.

**But keep in mind `$pop` will only remove 1 element.**